# PyDev - in Eclipse Oxygen "show in System explorer" absent for Python project; available in Java Project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In Java project I can show anything in "System Explorer". Why for python project I cannot do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Press **ALT + SHIFT + W** after select some file.

[image]